# Rails Complex Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, ruby-on-rails-5, polymorphic-associations

I have models called Rep and Bill. What I want to do is to populate two fields on the Bills form called sponsor and cosponsor. I want to populate the sponsor and cosponsor fields using a select box with a list of all the Reps that can accept multiple selections. I know how to set up the select box with the reps populating the select with multiple true. My question is how do I set up this type of association? Should I create separate models called sponsor and cosponsor and is this the appropriate situation to use has_many through or polymorphic associations?

Comment: Hi Taylor. You should provide more information on the behaviour of your objects, or maybe some code of the approach you have in mind. It is difficult to assume the best design without knowing what requirements are  involved. Anyway, I wanted to recommend you this book: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Practical-Object-Oriented-Design-Ruby-Addison-Wesley/dp/0321721330
Trust me, it will give you a whole new horizon about software design.
Look for the author on youtube(Sandi Metz), you won't regret it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't as complex as I had initially thought, I was able to use has_many through relationship in order to have the join table be sponsor or cosponsor.